# Define Bundle Path With Capistrano

Tags: rvm, capistrano, bundler

I am using the following configurations in my deploy.rb file for capistrano:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require 'rvm/capistrano'

set :bundle_cmd, "/home/deployment/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/bundle"

set :default_environment, {
    'PATH' => "/home/deployment/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/deployment/.rvm/bin:$PATH",
    'RUBY_VERSION' => 'ruby 1.9.3',
    'GEM_HOME' => "/home/deployment/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194",
    'GEM_PATH' => "/home/deployment/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194",
    'BUNDLE_PATH' => "/home/deployment/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
}
```

But when I run `cap deploy:update` I get this:

```
* executing "cd /var/www/currienet/marketplace/releases/20120928140140 && /home/deployment/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/bundle install --gemfile /var/www/currienet/marketplace/releases/20120928140140/Gemfile --path /var/www/currienet/marketplace/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
```

That is, it's not setting the bundle path (the --path argument) to what I want it to be.

I've tried a number of tutorials, including the [rvm capistrano tutorial](https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/#gem) but nothing seems to work. It continues to use the capistrano default.

Capistrano also creates an application with the following .bundler/config

```
BUNDLE_FROZEN: '1'
BUNDLE_PATH: /var/www/currienet/marketplace/shared/bundle
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test
```

Development Machine: Windows 7, bundler (1.0.22), capistrano (2.12.0), rvm-capistrano (1.2.7), rails (3.2.8), (no rvm)

Production: Debian, bundler (1.2.1) (no capistrano), (no rvm-capistrano), rails (3.2.8), rvm 1.16.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [Joseph Holsten's blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20120622085031/http://blog.josephholsten.com/2010/09/deploying-with-bundler-and-capistrano) I was able to ascertain my problem was I was not defining the bundler variables in my deploy.rb before I required 'bundler/capistrano'. I also needed to define the bundle_dir variable, to create code that looks like the following:

```
set :bundle_cmd, "/home/deployment/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/bundle"
set :bundle_dir, "/home/deployment/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"

require 'bundler/capistrano'
```