# Capsistrano, Gemfile not found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, jruby, puma

I'm using jruby 1.7, puma and capistrano with rails 4 applications.

Currently I have 1 command that capistrano can't run:

```
Command: 
cd /path_to_my_application/deploy/releases/20141209190535 && ( PATH=$HOME/jdk/bin:$PATH RAILS_ENV=staging ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )

DEBUG[d1a0d859]     Could not locate Gemfile
```

Before I had the error with this command which did get same error message `Could not locate Gemfile`

```
Command: cd /path_to_my_application/deploy/releases/20141209190535 && ( PATH=$HOME/jdk/bin:$PATH ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --binstubs /path_to_my_application/deploy/shared/bin --gemfile path_to_my_application/current/my_app/Gemfile --path /apath_to_my_application/deploy/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet )
```

But then I added these lines

`set :bundle_gemfile, "#{release_path}/housingsystem/Gemfile"
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = "bundle exec rake"` to my `my_app/config/deploy/staging.rb` and then it started working, until the precompile task started saying `Could not locate Gemfile`

Any idea what might be causing this?

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  # Use Capistrano for deployment
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'
  # Create architecture diagrams
  gem 'railroady'
end
```

My Capfile looks like this:

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Includes tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile

# https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
require 'capistrano/rvm'

# https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
require 'capistrano/bundler'

# https://github.com/capistrano/rails
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

# https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma
require 'capistrano/puma'

# https://github.com/javan/whenever#capistrano-v3-integration
require 'whenever/capistrano'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

So any idea why `PATH=$HOME/jdk/bin:$PATH RAILS_ENV=staging ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile`is telling me that Gemfile could not be found?

Comment: do you use rvm/rbenv?

Comment: yeah I use rvm for ruby version control

Comment: where is (please say) the gemfile? is it here `/path_to_my_application/deploy/releases/20141209190535`?

Comment: if yes try replace `bundle` to `~/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-x.x.x@projectX/bundle` and `~` to `/home/user` of your user

Comment: I added bundle manually based on the last answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641837/define-bundle-path-with-capistrano

but still I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

try to set

```
set :puma_prune_bundler, true
```

https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/329